# midpoint of arc when have Lat/longs A and B and Centre and radius

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

I have the following Lat/long points A (centre), B (start) and C(end) and the radius (orange line)

start point is -14.421667 145.086389

end point is -16.050833 143.278056

centre point is -16.850278 145.743889

I am trying to find the lat/long value of point D.

```
var angle = Math.atan2(start.lat, start.lng) - Math.atan2(end.lat, end.lng);
```

I have tried using atan2 (but is that in regards to the X axis?, what is correct order of lat/longs in the equation?) but the value returned doesn't seem correct so struggling to get the correct angle for CAB.... should then be able to divide angle by 2 and using that angle and point b and radius can get D... correct?

Also any hints on how to handle when the CAB angle is > 180degrees?

[image]

Note: picture rotation is not quite correct for the points given)

Thank you!

Comment: See [Compute angle between two points in a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715008/compute-angle-between-two-points-in-a-sphere). As for angles greater than 180 degrees, note that, on a sphere, there are usually two answers. Without more information, you can't tell which is the one you want. Usually you want the narrowest angle which is always <= 180 degrees.